# ¿Como pintar un texto escogiendo colores con checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero pintar un texto según escoja los colores del checkbox

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById("color1").addEventListener("click", pintar)
  document.getElementById("color2").addEventListener("click", pintar)
  document.getElementById("color3").addEventListener("click", pintar)

})

function pintar(e) {
  if (e.target.id == color1) {
    $("#noticia1").css("color", "red");
  }
  if (e.target.id == color2) {
    $("#noticia1").css("color", "azul");
  }
  if (e.target.id == color3) {
    $("#noticia1").css("color", "verde");
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="color1"> ROJO
<input type="checkbox" id="color2"> AZUL
<input type="checkbox" id="color3"> VERDE

<div id="noticia1">"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis</div>
```

Comment: Esto es realmente un fallo tipográfico: te faltan comillas en las comparaciones. Tal y como está ahora, estás comparando con las variables `color1`, `color2` y `color3` cuando lo que quieres es comparar con las cadenas de texto `"color1"`, `"color2"` y `"color3"`. Al poner las comillas se soluciona el problema.

Comment: igual no funciona :c

Answer (score 1):

Hay dos problemas en el código:

1. **Tienes fallos tipográficos**: te faltan comillas en las comparaciones. Tal y como está ahora, estás comparando con las variables `color1`, `color2` y `color3` cuando lo que quieres es comparar con las cadenas de texto `"color1"`, `"color2"` y `"color3"`. Al poner las comillas se soluciona el problema.
2. **Usas códigos de color incorrectos**: intentas cambiar a colores que no existen. Los códigos de color `azul` y `verde` no son válidos, debes usar `blue` y `green` respectivamente. Puedes ver una lista de los colores permitidos en la [página de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/color_value).

Corrigiendo esas dos cosas, ya funciona:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById("color1").addEventListener("click", pintar)
  document.getElementById("color2").addEventListener("click", pintar)
  document.getElementById("color3").addEventListener("click", pintar)

})

function pintar(e) {
console.log(e.target.id);
  if (e.target.id == "color1") {
    $("#noticia1").css("color", "red");
  }
  if (e.target.id == "color2") {
    $("#noticia1").css("color", "blue");
  }
  if (e.target.id == "color3") {
    $("#noticia1").css("color", "green");
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="color1"> ROJO
<input type="checkbox" id="color2"> AZUL
<input type="checkbox" id="color3"> VERDE

<div id="noticia1">"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis</div>
```

Comment: a muchas gracias :D, error de novato xD

Answer (score 1):

Esta solución podría servirte. Comento la lógica que he seguido punto por punto:

- He usado `$(function()` en lugar de `document.ready`, el cual es obsoleto desde jQuery 3
- Vamos a usar una clase que he llamado `checkBoxes` para todos los checkbox. Eso nos permitirá dos cosas: **a**. Poner **un sólo listener** para todos los checkbox, y  **.b** **deseleccionar cualquier otro cuando uno distinto haya sido seleccionado**. Eso impedirá tener más de un checkbox seleccionado a la vez. Creo que sería lo deseable para este caso.
- El color que se quiere establecer debe ser un color válido (escrito en inglés). Si quieres establecer un color usando `azul`, `rojo`, etc (como estabas haciendo), no funcionará. Como ignoro si piensas usar el atributo `id` de los checkbox para otra cosa, he recurrido en cada uno al atributo `value`, que sería además el más adecuado para este uso. Al seleccionar el checkbox, se recupera el `value` (escrito en inglés) y se establece como color del texto.
- El código queda de este modo optimizado. Como podrás apreciar, el anterior código era repetitivo. Para este tipo de casos es mejor agrupar los elementos por clases y luego usar `this`, para recuperar cualquier atributo/valor del elemento que fue clickeado o cambiado y trabajar con él. ¡Imagina el ahorro de código y lo que ganas en claridad, si fueran 10 ó 20 checkbox en vez de 3!

De ese modo el código queda simplificado, optimizado y hace lo que requieres.

```js
$(function() {

  $('input.checkBoxes').on('change', function() {
    $('input.checkBoxes').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    var cssColor = this.value;
    var $elDiv = $("#noticia1");
    $elDiv.css("color", cssColor);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="color1" value="red" class="checkBoxes"> ROJO
<input type="checkbox" id="color2" value="blue" class="checkBoxes"> AZUL
<input type="checkbox" id="color3" value="green" class="checkBoxes"> VERDE
<div id="noticia1">"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis"</div>
```